# How to return all properties and their values of an object including iterable ones, custom ones and inherited ones?

Tags: javascript

So far, I've learnt:

1) the `for` loop, I can use to iterate over indices in an object such as an array that has keys that were numeric indices.

2) the `for..in` loop gives me both iterable and custom properties and inherited properties, too. However, it leaves out properties whose values are undefined.

For e.g.

```
var array = [ 'Apples', , 'Pear' ];

array.newFn = function () { };
Array.prototype.anotherFn = function() { };
array.foo = bar;

for (var prop in array)
  console.log(prop);
```

will leave out index `1` because its value is `undefined`.

It will, however, iterate over `newFn`, `anotherFn` and `foo`.

3) The `for..of` iterates over values instead of keys. The difference is that it iterates over all iterable properties only, leaving out custom ones and also leaving out those inherited from the prototype chain. In doing so, however, includes those values where either the property key or the property value or both have the value `undefined`. Again, it includes this only for the iterable, own properties of the object.

Is there a looping construct that iterates over:

1. All iterable properties; and
2. Custom ones; and
3. Those inerhited from prototypes all the way down?

And iterates over the keys? Once I have the keys, I can get the values.

If there isn't an in-built looping construct, there must be some reflective property on `Object` named `keys` or some such that lets me peek into it?

Comment: What is expected result of index `1` of `array`? `undefined`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes.

Comment: _"will leave out index 1 because its value is undefined"_ not because its value is undefined, but because the key is undefined. Meaning there is no object property named `1` defined.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you. I stand corrected. I wasn't taking the time to articulate that thought.

Comment: By "iterable", you mean "enumerable"? Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to set the index to `undefined` using [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void). You can alternatively use `null`.

```js
var array = [ 'Apples', void 0, 'Pear' ];

array.newFn = function () { };
Array.prototype.anotherFn = function() { };
array.foo = "bar";

for (var prop in array)
  console.log(prop);
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems not to iterate over the properties inherited from the prototype chain.

Comment: It looks like the `for..in` will do it with an explicit setting of the gaps to be `undefined` as your code demonstrates in the array initializer.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Yes, you are correct. `Object.keys()` will also get the property names of `array`. See updated post.

Comment: Thank you. Is `void 0` a literal that represents `undefined`? That was going to be my next question.

Comment: `void` is an operator that evaluates expressions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void. You could alternative use `null`

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: `Object.keys` should not be part of this answer - OP wants to enumerate inherited properties as well.

Comment: @Bergi Updated.